# Margin before leading with auto layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

How should I add a margin before the leading of a text view using constraints?

I mean, if it is a left-right language I want to add a margin to the left, but if it is a right-left language I want to add a margin to the right.

Is there a constraint I could use in both cases to solve both situations? Or they are different constraints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use constraints at all for this purpose. UITextView has a property, textContainerInset, that you can set to put insets for your text on either the left or right (or both if you want).

Comment: Thanks! I've added the condition of using constraints in the question as it's a conceptual question, but I appreciate your answer

Comment: @axelbrz, if you want to use constraints, you would normally have constraints to both edges (or one edge and a width constraint). You could make IBOutlets to those constraints, and modify their constant values in code to move the text view right or left.

Comment: @rdelmar, there ARE the NSLayoutAtributes Trailing and Leading just for what he's asking. I'm trying to figure it out now but I think if you have a RTL language and specify those constraints, each constraint that has a leading as attribute is interpreted as referring to the right side (inverse for trailing), and for those constraints the constant value is inverted.